# Difference between JRE and Java Plugin

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, java

I read here
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-141825.html
JRE 1.4 (includes Java Plug-in 1.4)

What's difference between JRE and Plug-in ? What's the use of plugin ? Is it used by Firefox and Chrome ?

When installing Chrome will it install Plug-in itself ? If yes what if Google Chrome install a plugin version and the JRE version is lower ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, JRE plug-in is the one used by browser to run applets etc.,

You can install and un-install browser plugins through settings (these settings are browser specific).

Comment: When installing Chrome will it install Plug-in itself ? If yes what if Google Chrome install a plugin version and the JRE version is lower ?

Answer (score 2):

The JRE is the Java runtime, allowing a machine to run a Java program.
You can run the java process and specify an entry point class (program) which has a "main" method. Execution starts in your main method and continues from there. This is usually referred to as a Java application.

The plugin is bundled with the JRE, and runs inside a browser, allowing Java code to run inside the browser process on the client. 
The main entry point class must be written as an Applet when the plugin is used, but all the Java code it calls can be just regular Java.

Often it's more convenient to develop your application and run it as a Java application, then deploy it to your users as an applet. Most of the code can be identical.

Comment: When installing Chrome will it install Plug-in itself ? If yes what if Google Chrome install a plugin version and the JRE version is lower ?

Comment: You really want to get Java and the plugin from Oracle/Sun rather than anyone else. I don't think Chrome installs the Java plugin, no.

Comment: yes but chrome has a dedicated url from oracle why is it different from others ?

Comment: I imagine it's packaged slightly differently for different browsers. And maybe they want to track which browser people are installing on, and give the user a download page related to their browser for some sort of comfort factor

Answer (score 2):

The JRE is the Java Runtime Environment, i.e. the software you need to interpret and execute Java class files. The Java browser plugin is the bridge between the JRE and the browser, used to run Java classes of applets embedded in HTML.

There are limitations when running Java code with the Java plugin for security reasons. All code is run in a sandbox with limited access to the file system and such (although you can exceed those limits with explicit user permission / proper signing).

Comment: When installing Chrome will it install Plug-in itself ? If yes what if Google Chrome install a plugin version and the JRE version is lower ?

Comment: There is no relation between the Java plugin version and the version of your JRE. Good chance your plugin version is greater than your JRE's version. Mine is 14.3.0 (see chrome://plugins/).

Comment: yes but some stuff doesn't seem to work if you have plugin 7 with jre 6