# Java is recognized in Command Prompt but I can't install any program that requires Java?

Tags: java, cmd

So, when I type `java -version` in `cmd`, it gives the right result like this

```
C:\Windows\System32>java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

I take it that java has been installed properly on my laptop. But when I try to install any program that requires Java, the program will give an error saying that I don't have java. Also my browsers (Mozilla Firefox and Chrome) say that they can't run Java. I have no idea why.

Comment: maybe the program you are trying to install is looking for an older version of java..

Comment: The error says "Unable to find JRE 1.6.0 or a later version on your system." I have java 1.8.0 installed on my laptop which means it is later than what's required by the program :/

Comment: The mistake people tend to make is that they think Java 8 is an update of Java 7 and Java 7 is an update of Java 8. That is exactly not true, Java 8 is a new release of Java. The program you are attempting to use is built to want Java 6 specifically (probably to have zero chance of conflicts). Possibly you need a newer version of it too then if it requires such an outdated runtime.

Comment: As for browsers, there are possibly multiple problems going on. Chrome first of all no longer supports the Java plugin. Other browsers do, but you can run into this problem if the browser is for example 32 bits and the Java runtime you install is 64 bits. The 64 bits runtime will not be seen by a 32 bits browser.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Now if I for example install Java 6, will it remove Java 8 which is already installed or can I have them both side by side?

Comment: There also is a difference between the JRE (java.exe) and the Java Plugin. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568648/difference-between-jre-and-java-plugin

Comment: @AnnaRG no, you can safely have multiple releases of Java installed at once. If you would re-install or update Java 8 you will be asked to remove older releases however, since they are no longer patched they form a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

When you type

> C:\Windows\System32>java -version

It search java on your path, which means that somewhere there is a java on your computer. The problem is that some software don't look at your path to find java, they will need a specific environment variable (not very frequent). Other time they will search it in a specific place where oracle puts a shortcut to java when you use the installer.
Long story short, try to install java using the Oracle installer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I know how to add new classpath to the environment variables, but I didn't do it since I saw it's already recognized via cmd and assumed that I don't need to do this. So, if I add the classpath to the environment variable now it will work?

Comment: the system search path, not the classpath. The first biggest confusion people tend to have is that they think Java and Javascript are the same thing, the second biggest is that they mismatch PATH and CLASSPATH or even think they are one and the same.

Comment: I corrected my mistake, of course I meant path not classpath.